# I'm working on a CSV import script and keep getting a PHP Notice (Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object)

Tags: php

I'm working on an CSV import script. I've run into an notice that says "Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object".

```php
function getWardByCode($ward, $area_id){
    global $db;

    $query = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `wards` WHERE `code`='{$db->real_escape_string($ward)}', `area_id`='{$db->real_escape_string($area_id)}' LIMIT 1");

    if (1 === $query->num_rows){
        $data = $query->fetch_assoc();
        return $data['id'];
    }

    $db->query("INSERT INTO `wards` (`code`, `area_id`) VALUES ('{$db->real_escape_string($ward)}', '{$db->real_escape_string($area_id)}')");

    return $db->insert_id;
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($query);` give you?

Comment: Possibly your query crashed and returned false instead of a result object. Did you check that?

Comment: do var_dump($query);

Comment: console.log(num_rows); in PHP ? WTF ???

Comment: Thanks for your responses. var_dump($query) returns bool(false)

Comment: Because query text is invalid.

Comment: LOL @AndriiSukhoi, my mistake. But I already removed that.

Comment: @KyleMabaso :D I have same things sometimes when writing js + php in one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using mysqli extension.

If you look at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for `mysqli::query` it says:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object.

In your example you always assume that the query works, allowing you to access `mysqli_result::$num_rows`. But since you never check the return value of the query, when it fails you basically get something like `false->num_rows`. That's why you are getting that notice.

Now, to check why your query is failing you could try checking `$mysqli->error`, which in your example would be `$db->error`.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I got this:

string(170) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
 to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' `area_id`='1' LIM
IT 1' at line 1"

Thanks a million.